# How do I parse this PDE for the evolution of a probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, distribution-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06561.pdf) on page 5, the authors write equation (7):

$$\partial_t \rho_t = 2\xi(t)\nabla_\theta\cdot(\rho_t\nabla_\theta\Psi(\theta;\rho_t))$$

Where:

- $\rho_t$ for $t\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is a probability distribution on the "parameter space" $\mathbb R^d$.
- $\xi$ is some real-valued function.
- $\theta$ is an element of the parameter space $\mathbb R^d$.
- $\nabla\cdot$ refers to the divergence operator.
- $\Psi$ is a function accepting an element of $\mathbb R^d$ and a probability distribution as inputs and returning a real number.

I need some help first of all just *parsing* this thing, but also I could do with some references to get a foundation in the theory I need to understand what an equation like this even means. For example, I don't actually understand the expression

$$\rho_t\nabla_\theta\Psi(\theta;\rho_t)$$

I get that the $\nabla$ and everything after it collectively represents a vector field since for any $\theta$ that expression evaluates to a vector in $\mathbb R^d$, but I don't get what the $\rho_t$ is doing there. How do you multiply a vector by a probability measure? Since we then take the divergence, I suppose this whole expression must evaluate to a vector field, but I just don't know how to read it.

Comment: Is this really about [distribution-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))?

Comment: @md2perpe Well, I remember covering applications to PDEs in my one distribution theory class years ago, and I vaguely remember something about the notion of distributions as solutions to PDEs, and something about measures being a special case of distributions.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you knew what you did when adding the tag 'distribution-theory'. It's common that it's incorrectly added to posts that are only about probability-distributions.